# PyQt5: How to show another window/widget for a short time

Tags: python, pyqt5

Hi in my application I have main windows and when a data comes from another thread, I need to show it in another screen for 2 seconds and then go back to previous screen. Screens has many components so I made a simple version to demonstrate my purpose.

Data comes from another thread successfully I can change the text of label. However I can not make disappear the old one and apeear the new one.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMainWindow, QLabel, QWidget, QGridLayout, QVBoxLayout, QGroupBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextDocument
from PyQt5 import QtCore, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap, QFont
from time import strftime 
import datetime 
from babel.dates import format_date, format_datetime, format_time
import sys
import worker
import time


class Form(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.label_main = QLabel("Welcome")
        self.label_uid = QLabel("Exit") 
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self._width = 480
        self._height = 800

        self.layout_main = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout_access = QVBoxLayout()

        self.obj = worker.Worker()  # no parent!
        self.thread = QThread()  # no parent!
        self.obj.return_uid.connect(self.onCardRead)     
        self.obj.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.obj.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.obj.get_uid)
        self.thread.start()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setLayout(self.layout_main)
        self.layout_main.addWidget(self.label_main)
        self.setWindowTitle('Main Thread')
        self.show()

    def secondUI(self):
        self.setLayout(self.layout_access)
        self.layout_access.addWidget(self.label_uid)
        self.setWindowTitle('Access Thread')
        self.show()
```

Comment: Okay you kind of need a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to determine what you need here -- of course I do believe their might already be answers for this in Stackoverflow somewhere  ---  however to perhaps get you on the right track look into QTimer or just look into the python time.sleep function

Answer (score 0):

add self.windowname.close() or just self.close() after the show()

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    return_uid = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def get_uid(self): 
        print("start")
        count = 0
        QtCore.QThread.msleep(1000)
        while count < 10:
            QtCore.QThread.msleep(200)      
            self.return_uid.emit(count)
            count += 1
        self.finished.emit()


class Form(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.label_main = QLabel("Welcome")
        self.label_uid = QLabel("Exit") 

        self.layout_main = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout_access = QVBoxLayout()

#        self.obj = worker.Worker()  # no parent!
        self.obj = Worker()                           

        self.thread = QThread()     
        self.obj.return_uid.connect(self.onCardRead)     
        self.obj.moveToThread(self.thread)

#        self.obj.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.obj.finished.connect(self.close)

        self.thread.started.connect(self.obj.get_uid)
        self.thread.start()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setLayout(self.layout_main)
        self.layout_main.addWidget(self.label_main)
        self.setWindowTitle('Main Thread')
        self.show()

    def secondUI(self):
        self.setLayout(self.layout_access)
        self.layout_access.addWidget(self.label_uid)
        self.setWindowTitle('Access Thread')
        self.show()

    def onCardRead(self, id):
        self.label_main.setNum(id)            


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Form()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

---

**Update**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    return_uid = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def get_uid(self): 
        print("start")
        count = 0
        QtCore.QThread.msleep(1000)
        while count < 10:
            QtCore.QThread.msleep(500)      
            self.return_uid.emit(count)
            count += 1
        self.finished.emit()


class Form(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.label_main = QLabel("Welcome")
        self.label_uid = QLabel("Exit") 

        self.layout_main = QVBoxLayout()
#        self.layout_access = QVBoxLayout()

        self.obj = Worker()                           
        self.thread = QThread()     
        self.obj.return_uid.connect(self.onCardRead)     
        self.obj.moveToThread(self.thread)

#        self.obj.finished.connect(self.close)
        self.obj.finished.connect(self.secondUI)                # <---

        self.thread.started.connect(self.obj.get_uid)
        self.thread.start()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setLayout(self.layout_main)
        self.layout_main.addWidget(self.label_main)
        self.setWindowTitle('Main Thread')
        self.resize(300, 100)
        self.show()

    def secondUI(self):                                         # <---
        self.hide()
        self.windowSecond = QWidget()
        self.layout_access = QVBoxLayout(self.windowSecond)
        self.layout_access.addWidget(self.label_uid)
        self.windowSecond.setWindowTitle('Main Screen')
        self.windowSecond.resize(300, 200)
        self.windowSecond.show()

    def onCardRead(self, id):
        self.label_main.setNum(id)            


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Form()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: How to go back to main screen after displaying second one?